# Any framework / 3rd party tool for importing contacts from gmail, hotmail, yahoo mail, etc

Tags: php, email, import, contacts

We have an application in which we want to let our users invite other contacts in their email contact lists. We;re currently using OpenInviter and it seems like that requires users to enter their email accounts and passwords on our site... which is something which we would like to avoid...

A better solution would be something that uses OAuth - can someone recommend something like that in PHP? We're open to paid/better solutions that allow API access as well.

I've heard of a couple of 3rd party API providers - but not able to get  a clear picture of who's the market leader / most stable-reliable...

Matt

Answer (score 5):

Try Contact Grabber. 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3895-PHP-Grab-contacts-of-email-and-social-networking-sites.html

Comment: Edited and updated suggestion.